# Is there a function which will take schema name and table name and return all the column names in the table

Tags: python, sql, oracle

I am trying to use python to download a table from oracle database using CX_Oracle module

This below command is executed in a notebook along with the credential

```
temp = list()
for row in c.execute('SELECT * FROM dbname.tablename'):
        temp.append(row)
df = pd.DataFrame(temp)
```

I am able to get all the rows into the variable temp but. I also would like to get the column names as well.

So my approach was to get the column name separately and add them to the above df.

For a given schema name and a table name, I want to find the column names of that table in Oracle.

"This doesn't return anything so far but the column exsist '

```
select table_name
from all_tab_columns 
where column_name = 'modby'
```

Thanks in advance for your assistance

Answer (score 2):

By default, Oracle stores object and column names in uppercase, so try

```
select table_name
from all_tab_columns 
where column_name = 'MODBY'          --> instead of 'modby'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use upper or lower on both sides of comparison as Oracle DB behave case-sensitivity differently. `object names` (table, column, etc) are stored case-sensitively if they are wrapped in `"` while creating else oracle DB converts all the object names without double quotes into the `uppercase` name.

Try the following query:

```
select table_name
from user_tab_columns 
where lower(column_name) = 'modby'
```

If you want all column names of the table then try the following query:

```
select column_name
from user_tab_columns 
where lower(table_name) = lower('<your_table_name>');
```

Cheers!!

Comment: Thank you Tejash. I executed this command in the sql developer but for both the query I get nothing in the output window.

Comment: Can you please edit the question and share the ddl of the table?